# Vector of structs and I don't know what to do

Tags: c++, vector, struct, io

For each line of text:

```
-Get first name
-Get last name
-Get Student Number
```

(There will be an unknown amount of lines, each looking the same in format.)
Format:

```
First Last 111111111
First Last 111111112
...
```

I want to put each piece of each student into its own struct. I've set up the struct as follows:

```
struct Student{  
    string lastName;
    string firstName;
    string stdNumber;
    double assgn1;//doubles will be used later in prog.
    double assign2;
    double assign3;
    double assign4;
    double midTerm;
    double finalGrade;
};
```

My file input function is as follows:

```
int getFileInfo()
{       
    int failed=0;
    ifstream fin;   
    string fileName;    
    vector<Student> students;

    Student s;                  // A place to store data of one student
    cout<<"Please enter the filename of the student grades (ex. filename_1.txt)."<<endl;
    do{                                 
        if(failed>=1)                           
            cout<<"Please enter a correct filename."<<endl; 
        cin>>fileName;                              
        fin.open(fileName.c_str());// Open the file     
        failed++;                                           
    }while(!fin.good());                                        
    while (fin >> s.firstName >> s.lastName >> s.stdNumber)
        students.push_back(s);                      
    fin.close();                            
    return 0;                                   
}
```

In the file input, I make a vector, but I am unsure how to access each individual part of it, or the student, `s`, because it seems that it only makes one student. I was told that each line of the file is split and inputted into the `students` vector, but I don't know how to extract that information. How do I get each student out of the `students` vector and into its own struct so I can use each student as its own struct?
So in the end, I would want to be able to output:

```
Student1: First Last 111111111
Student2: First Last 111111112
However More students are in the file
```

Thanks in advance for the help!!

@Loki
I changed the loop so `loop != end` and I still get the same problem. Here is my code:

```
int getFileInfo()
{
int failed=0;
ifstream fin;
string fileName;
vector<Student> students;// A place to store the list of students
vector<Student>::iterator loop = students.begin();
   vector<Student>::iterator end  = students.end();

Student s;                  // A place to store data of one student
cout<<"Please enter the filename of the student grades (ex. filename_1.txt)."<<endl;
do{
if(failed>=1)
    cout<<"Please enter a correct filename."<<endl;
    cin>>fileName;
    fin.open(fileName.c_str());// Open the file
    failed++;
}while(!fin.good());

 while (fin >> s.firstName >> s.lastName >> s.stdNumber){
    cout<<"Reading "<<s.firstName<<" "<<s.lastName<<" "<<s.stdNumber<<endl;
    students.push_back(s);
}
fin.close();

    for(loop;loop!=end;++loop)
    cout<<loop->firstName<<" "<<loop->lastName<<" "<<loop->stdNumber<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Again, Visual studio is saying `vector iterators incompatible`,
 Pointing to "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\vc\include\vector"

Comment: Nothing fancy.Just read [ifstream::read()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/) each structure from the file and save it in the vector using [vector::push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/).

Comment: I already have the data removed from the text file and into the vector. It is getting the saved data from the vector of structs that I am having trouble with.

Comment: I added an answer, hope that helps you.

Comment: A bit more effort in formatting the input please. Read the markup section for the site. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Note when you edit/write text this link is available via the question mark at the top right of the edit box.http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74999/138817

Comment: @LokiAstari I'll make sure to do that next time. Thanks for fixing it this time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the file input, I make a vector, but I am unsure how to access each individual part of it.

You can access individual elements via the operator[]

```
students[0].firstName;  // get the first name.

std::cout << students[1].firstName; // prints out the first name.
```

You can use an index from 0 -> size().

```
size_t  size = students.size();  // number of students in the vector.

students[size].firstName; // This is wrong. You expression in
                          // [] must be less than size as the elements are
                          // numbered from 0 to size() -1.
```

> because it seems that it only makes one student.

You are creating only one student 's' (As a side not pick a better name). But when you call push_back() you are copying this student object into the vector. So the vector gets a copy of 's' that it stores. Then each time through the loop you overwrite the old values in 's' with new values retrieved from the file.

> I was told that each line of the file is split and inputted into the students vector, but I don't know how to extract that information.

As noted above each element can be reached individually using the operator[]

Alternatively you can use iterators to get a range. of students.

```
 std::vector<Student>::iterator loop = students.begin();
 std::vector<Student>::iterator end  = students.end();
```

You can access an element by de-referencing loop and move to the next student by incrementing loop.

```
 std::cout << loop->firstName;   // prints out student[0]
 ++loop;                         // Increment loop now it points at student 1
 std::cout << loop->firstName;   // prints out student[1]
 ++loop;                         // Increment loop now it points at student 2
 // etc
```

If loop == end then you have moved past all the students.

> How do I get each student out of the students vector and into its own struct so I can use each student as its own struct?

The students are in the vector already in structs. you can use them directly as you would a struct outside. But if you want to copy them out you can do this:

```
Student   tmp = students[0]; // copies student 0 into tmp.
```

> I would want to be able to output:

Use std::cout to output stuff to the standard output. Or create an object of type std::ofstream to output to a file:

```
std::cout << tmp.lastName  << " " 
          << tmp.firstName << " "
          << tmp.stdNumber << "\n";

std::ofstream  file("plop1.txt");
file      << tmp.lastName  << " " 
          << tmp.firstName << " "
          << tmp.stdNumber << "\n";
```

Comment: When I try to output using the `std::cout`, it gave me a popup window that says `"Debug Assertion Failed!"` `Expression: Vector iterator not dereferencable."` Any Idea what that means? I could see a problem being in a de-referencing loop with something that is non-dereferencable...

Comment: Did you try and de-reference the iterator that was passed the end (as indicated by the iterator returned by end()).

Comment: I made a for loop: `for(loop;loop==end;++loop)` Now it says `vector iterators incompatible`. Can you explain?

Comment: Small bug there: Make sure it is `for(loop;loop!=end;++loop)` But rather than converse in comments edit your question.

Comment: It compiles fine, but it's a run-time error I get. After `fin.close()`

Comment: Sorry: Once you add something to a vector the old iterators become invalid. You should call begin()/end() after all the students have been added (ie just before the loop).

Comment: Thanks @Loki this pretty much answered this question! I have one final question, but I made a new post for it.

Answer (score 2):

**[Online Demo Sample:](http://ideone.com/M33Yp)**

```
#include<iostream>     
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

struct Student
{
    string lastName;
    string firstName;
    string stdNumber;
    double assgn1;//doubles will be used later in prog.
    double assign2;
    double assign3;
    double assign4;
    double midTerm;
    double finalGrade;
};

int main()
{
    Student obj;
    obj.firstName = "ABC";
    obj.lastName = "XYZ";

    vector<Student> students;
    students.push_back(obj);
    vector<Student>::iterator it;

    cout << "students contains:";
    for ( it=students.begin() ; it != students.end(); ++it )
    {
        cout << " " << (*it).firstName;
        cout << " " << (*it).lastName;
        //And so on...
    }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `it < students.end()`? Shouldn't it be `it != students.end()`? Also, prefer `++it` over `it++`.

Comment: @Nawaz: Well spotted.I was in a edit ctually but thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! @Als I tried that in my code and ran it, it gave me a popup window that says `"Debug Assertion Failed!"` Expression: `Vector iterator not dereferencable."` Any Idea what that means?